# I feel uncomfotable with my cursor

Tags: cursor

When I use my laptop with Ubuntu I face this issue that my cursor is not user friendly... I just feel like it drags the point from where I want it to be when I select something and when

Comment: This is not normal and may be an issue with your graphics driver. You will need to post more information about your system - Ubuntu version, computer, graphics card. Maybe you need proprietary drivers to get your video properly working. You can check in "Software & Updates", "Additional Drivers" tab where the system will suggest whether and which proprietary drivers might be available. Sometimes it is the reverse, and one gets better performance removing a proprietary driver.

Comment: thank you very.much. I think i have corrected it with the suggestion you have offered